# WordPress I changed database user password and site cannot connect database since

Tags: wordpress, database-connection, bluehost

I recently changed my user password at the Bluehost database and since then my website doesn't work. The page shows: Error establishing a database connection. I tried to change the password back but it doesn't work. Can you help me to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only time that WordPress doesn’t like it if you change the database password is if you don’t change in on the database user and in the `wp-config.php` file. Both have to be done together.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database-name');
define('DB_USER', 'database-username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'database-password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 3):

If you changed the user/pass of the database, you also have to change the user and password in the wp-config.php file which is in the wordpress root directory.